# Why is my edit spam?

Tags: support

I've tried to edit "Nico-nico-nii~♡" into another user's post.

[image]

Link: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/966368

This edit is not intended to promote services nor it is destructive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By adding nothing more than

> -nico-nii~ ♡

You are defacing the post while adding absolutely nothing of value.

Edits should, as a minimum, not make the post worse. Preferably edits should be used to improve questions and answers, not to deface them or add pointless signatures.

Please read our guidelines on [editing posts.](https://superuser.com/help/editing)

Comment: In fact the edit should have removed the signature, not added additional text, to the signature the author.  There are other grammatical issues in that particular question.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree that the edit was headed in the wrong direction in that it was adding yet more noise on top of what was already there and that it should have been removing the existing signature as well as making other corrections. I chose to limit my answer to what specifically made this edit *awful* and to show that while it may not have been "spam" or "destructive" per their question here. It was still defacement and, at best, absolutely worthless as an edit.

Comment: Do you know what Nico-nico-nii means?

Comment: @ii-V-Icadence I am aware of the vague meaning of the phrase as well as its relevance to anime memes. Even if I didn't would that change the fact that it shouldn't have been edited into the question in the first place?

Comment: @Mokubai see [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/what-does-nico-nico-nii-mean).  I am trying to act cute via those edits.  Why is this not good?

Comment: @ii-V-Icadence I fail to see any argument in "acting cute" that makes it a valid edit. Why exactly do you think it is in any way "good"? I've already stated why it **is not** good, it is your turn to say why it **is** good.

Comment: @KotoriMinami - Your edit proposal was not a valid suggestion, the best reason of a static list was selected, please don’t introduce “cute” edits